# Function template specialization for pointer

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

In our code base we have a template

```
template<typename DT>
void f(const DT&) {}
```

with some specializations. One specialization is

```
template<>
void f(const int*&) {}
```

When I try to use it, clang gives me

```
error: no function template matches function template specialization 'f'
void f(const int*&) {}

note: candidate template ignored: cannot deduce a type for 'DT' that would make 'const DT' equal 'const int *'
void f(const DT&) {}
```

An example code is

```
template<typename DT>
void f(const DT&) {}

template<>
void f(const int*&) {}

int main() {
    const int *a = nullptr;
    f(a);
}
```

Why is it not possible to specialize this template for a pointer type? How can I achieve the specialization?

Comment: Have you tried `template<> void f<const int*&>(const int*&) {}`?

Comment: @DynamicSquid that would silence the error similar to  `using int_p = int *; template<> void f(const int_p&) {}`. But `f(a);` wouldn't call the specialized function, but `template<typename DT> void f(const DT&) {}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that in the primary template, `const` is qualified on the type `DT` itself. Suppose you want to specialize it with type `DT` as `const int*` (i.e. pointer to `const` `int`), then the specialization should be

```
template<>
void f(const int* const&) {} // reference to const (pointer to const int)
//                ^^^^^
```

Let's check the primary template again, to compare and confirm the type:

```
template<typename DT>
void f(const DT&) {} // reference to const (DT)
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sSDrLQ6jyWDWjfRt)

Comment: Or perhaps just `int *const&`, for `DT = int*`. Also, and this is just my opinion, but I think it's better style to actually flip the order of `const` in types. If the OP had written `int const*&`, I think it would have been clearer what was wrong. I also think it reads better, according to the spiral rule: `const int *const&` is "reference to constant pointer to integer constant," but `int const *const&` is "reference to constant pointer to constant integer".